# The CLI refers to the Chocolatey's NodeJs PATH but never finds it

Tags: node.js, chocolatey

I'm desperate. After installation Nodejs-LTS with Chocolatey for 'node -v'I got following error:

> Cannot find file at '..\lib\nodejs.commandline\tools\node.exe' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.commandline\tools\node.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.
> Meanwhile the NPM show his version.

After deleting in Chocolatey and manually installed nodejs-lts I have the same issue in this environment.
For some reason, it always refers to **Chocolatey's path**, no matter what CLI I use. Manually setted PATH variables with path to Nodejs (C/ProgramFiles/nodejs) didn't help.
I'm desperate.

Need to mention I have tried next:

Delete Nodejs, install manually. Restart. Same result.

Add PATH variables. Restart. Same result.

Delete Nodejs, install it with Chocotey again. Restart. Same result.

Delete nodejs package in Chocolatey. Install NVM and nodejs. Restart. Same result.

open the folder with nodejs C:\Program Files\nodejs and ... node -v the same result

Comment: What happens when you execute `nodevars.bat` from the directory `C:\Program Files\nodejs` ?

Comment: @Luuk

PS C:\Program Files\nodejs> **nodevars.bat**
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 18.17.0 (x64) and npm.
PS C:\Program Files\nodejs> **node -v**
Cannot find file at '..\\lib\nodejs.commandline\tools\node.exe' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.commandline\tools\node.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.
PS C:\Program Files\nodejs>

Comment: Do you have `nodejs.commandline` installed, please try to remove it, it is deprecated, see: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs.commandline

Comment: Updated choco to 2.2.0. Choco list doesn't show **nodejs.commandline**. But I found packge in previously deleted choco packages in **C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\nodejs.commandline** delete it manually. Doesn't help unfortunatly. Looks like once I tried downgrade Nodejs version and nodejs.commandline was included or something :/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got a shim for `node.exe` that hasn't been cleaned up that's ahead of anything else in PATH (though this somewhat depends on how you mean "Manually setted PATH variables with path to Nodejs".)

I'd suggest looking in `$env:ChocolateyInstall\bin` (default location: `C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin`) for a `node.exe` file, and removing it if you don't currently have the NodeJS.CommandLine package installed (which, as Luuk pointed out, is a deprecated package at this point).

If you want to do this in PowerShell, you could use the following:

```bash
# Check to see if the package exists
$Package = choco list nodejs.commandline --local-only --exact --limit-output

# Path to expected shim file
$NodeShim = Join-Path $env:ChocolateyInstall "bin\node.exe"

# If the shim exists, but the package isn't present
if (Test-Path $NodeShim -and -not $Package) {
  # Clean up the shim
  Remove-Item $NodeShim
} else {
  Write-Warning "No unused shim for Node.exe was found."
}
```

For what it's worth, this has likely happened because you've previously had an install of NodeJS using the `nodejs.commandline` package (which [downloads an exe](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs.commandline#files) and shims it), and your recent attempt to install used `NodeJS-LTS` (which [uses the NodeJS MSI installation](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs-lts#files)).

This would potentially result in a broken shim ahead on the PATH if something cleaned up the lib files manually (which isn't recommend).

Comment: After doing this, the directory "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.commandline" **should** no longer exists, and not be in your PATH environment variable anymore.  (Should because I cannot test this locally because I do not have that directory)

Comment: Just for clarity: it seems like that directory already doesn't exist, and isn't on PATH (or shouldn't be, based on what we know about these packages). The directory-path is in the error message in OP because of the relative-path the shim is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am unable to reproduce your issue.

I did not have node installed on my system, and followed `choco install nodejs-lts`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2070]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\TEMP>echo %PATH% | findstr /i node

D:\TEMP>choco install nodejs-lts
Chocolatey v2.2.0
3 validations performed. 2 success(es), 1 warning(s), and 0 error(s).

Validation Warnings:
 - System Cache directory is not locked down to administrators.
   Remove the directory 'C:\ProgramData\ChocolateyHttpCache' to have
   Chocolatey CLI create it with the proper permissions.

Installing the following packages:
nodejs-lts
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading nodejs-lts 18.17.0... 100%

nodejs-lts v18.17.0 [Approved]
nodejs-lts package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package nodejs-lts wants to run 'chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint): Y

Installing 64 bit version
Installing nodejs-lts...
nodejs-lts has been installed.
  nodejs-lts may be able to be automatically uninstalled.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
 The install of nodejs-lts was successful.
  Software installed as 'MSI', install location is likely default.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

**Restarting command-prompt**, (did you do that?), shows:

```
D:\TEMP>where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

D:\TEMP>node -v
v18.17.0

D:\TEMP>choco -v
2.2.0
```

Comment: For 'where node' nothing happends, just next command line opens
choco -v
1.2.1

Comment: This new environment is a my new laptop. 5 minutes ago I calmly installed nodejs on someone else's laptop so that I can work. Like did it year before on corporative laptop. Though manually, not with Chocolatey. But still I cant use my laptop without totally rewrite environment or create new one :'(

Comment: version 1.2.1 is old, there do exist multiple newer versions, see: https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/release-notes.  Is there any reason why you did not update to a newer version?